# Bootstrap's tabs with data-toggle cause reload in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just migrated to AngularJS 1.2. And I've realized that all my menu/navigation elements that were configured with data-toggle, for instance:

```
<li><a href="#additionalSelection" data-toggle="tab">Additional Selection</a></li>
```

are not working any more. They should toggle element with id="additionalSelection" - and this is how Angular & Bootstrap worked when I was using version 1.0.8 of Angular.

But now, when I click anchor element, Angular intercepts this click and tries to go to route **additionalSelection** and it causes page refresh...

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Could you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The solution is as simple as replacing **href** attribute with **data-target**. That solves the issue:

```
<li><a data-target="#additionalSelection" data-toggle="tab">Additional Selection</a></li>
```

Comment: literally was stuck on this for the afternoon ( well, it was basically because i confused scrolling to mean selecting a tab lol and was unfruitfully looking at solutions using $anchorScroll :P ). This is perfect for BS3, i didn't want to pull in the angular-bootstrap-ui module just for this! Thank you

Comment: I had the same problem. The solution worked. It stopped redirecting. But the list now doesnot expand or collpase. Can anyone help?

Comment: The above solution (also exactly the same in [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)) only works when _not_ using Angular, at least for certain versions. I am assuming this is why the Angular folks created this library [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) as a workaround to these sorts of conflicts. Haven't investigated it fully to understand exactly the conflict, but [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together) sheds some light on possibly related conflicts due to jQuery.

Comment: In a nutshell, since I ran out of space in the above comment, here is a snippet from the article: "This is why we can’t just use Bootstrap JavaScript. It relies on jQuery and we don’t want jQuery rummaging around our Angular projects. If we try to bind variables to the components, it won’t work."

Comment: I thought I might have to break my head with this but such a simple fix. I was having issues using bootstrap tab alongside backbone router.

Comment: You saved my time.

Answer (score 9):

As `dragonfly` pointed out, `data-target` works fine instead of `href`.

There is a small difference in CSS. When **data-target** is used vs **href**, the cursor is not a **pointer** anymore. If you don't want to add extra CSS, you can do the following:

```
<a href="#additionalSelection" data-toggle="tab" onclick="return false;">Selection</a>
```

> This is just a suggestion, not an elegant solution. But if you want to use href for some reason, add `onclick="return false;"`

Answer (score 5):

Simply replace `href` attribute from `data-target`

```
<li><a data-target="#switchTabs" data-toggle="tab">Tabs</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution preserving the cursor (while still relying on data-target instead of href to navigate) is:

```
<li><a href="" data-target="#additionalSelection" data-toggle="tab">Additional Selection</a></li>
```

the addition of href causes the cursor to switch to the hand, but leaving it blank as "" doesn't cause any page reloads.