# Using bootstrap collapse with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to include the below bootstrap collapsible panel in my angular application. However, when I click on "Expand", angular seems to see `href="#collapseOne"` and then redirects to the home page instead of collapsing the panel. My routing looks like this, and I think the `otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});` is causing the problem. Any suggestions?

```
angular.module('App')
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { 
$routeProvider.
  when('/users', {templateUrl: 'partials/users/user-list.html', controller: 'UserCtrl'}).
  when('/users/new', {templateUrl: 'partials/users/user-new.html', controller: 'UserNewCtrl'}).
  when('/users/:userid', {templateUrl: 'partials/users/user-detail.html', controller: 'UserDetailCtrl'}).


  otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

The panel-

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Expand
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As mentionned in a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930383/bootstraps-tabs-with-data-toggle-cause-reload-in-angularjs), simply change your href by the data-target attribute

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
          Expand
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works. But you should also add an empty href to make the browser show the hand pointer when the mouse is placed over the link

Comment: I had the same problem. The given solution stops from redirecting to home page but the problem now is the list does not expand or collapse now. can anyone help?

Comment: It does not work at all. I am facing same issue like @prabu

Comment: This works thanks bro.. But only for Static content.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the accordion directive from [AngularJS UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) that builds on top of twitter bootstrap the collapse directive.

**example:**

```
 <accordion >
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="true">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
 </accordion>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/U89bW/3/

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, and I didn't want to add an additional library beyond bootstrap.  As recommended, you can use`data-target="#your-collapsing-element"`, removing the `href` attribute completely.

## The basics

To make a panel collapse you need:

1. On the element used to trigger collapse:

   ```
   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-collapsing-element"
   ```
2. On the element that collapses:

   ```
   id="my-collapsing-element"
   ```
3. On the element wrapping both the "trigger" element and the collapsing element:

   ```
   class="panel"
   ```

## Putting it all together

You can optionally add parent elements to make it part of a group, and add add the css classes "`collapse in`" to the collapsing element to make its default state closed. A full example:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="panel">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">
            Heading 1
        </a>
        <div id="collapse1">
            Content for panel 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse2">
            Heading 2
        </a>
        <div id="collapse2" class="collapse in">
            Content for panel 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can get better button behaviors by using a `<button>` element rather than an `<a>`. Overriding bootstrap's styling for `.panel` can be done by adding your own styling for the `panel` css class.

`<div class="panel its-my-panel">`

```
.panel.its-my-panel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```css
.my-panel-heading {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Overrides for .panel--theonly required bootstrap class */

.panel.my-panel-overrides {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="panel my-panel-overrides">
    <a class="my-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">
        Collapsible Group 1</a>
    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse in">
      Content for panel 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel my-panel-overrides">
    <a class="my-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
    <div id="collapse2" class="collapse">
      Content for panel 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel my-panel-overrides">
    <a class="my-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse3">
        Collapsible Group 3</a>
    <div id="collapse3" class="collapse">
      Content for panel 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Change all `href` in order to expand-collapse to `data-target`.
2. `data-target` and `id` of the `div` to be expanded and collapsed should not contain hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Click the buttons below to show and hide another element via class changes:

- **collapse** hides content
- **collapsing** is applied during transitions
- **collapse**.in shows content

You can use a link with the **href** attribute, or a button with the **data-target** attribute. In both cases, the **data-toggle="collapse"** is required.

check this example below.

[Bootsrap Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse)

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
       <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
        Expand
       </a>
     </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
    ...
   </div>
 </div>
```