# Bootstrap Accordion redirects page in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I did my research on this and noted that there are 2 topics similar to this.

[Bootstrap's tabs with data-toggle cause reload in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930383/bootstraps-tabs-with-data-toggle-cause-reload-in-angularjs)

and

[Using bootstrap collapse with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436237/using-bootstrap-collapse-with-angularjs)

Both mentioned to replace  **href**  tag with **data-target**

So I did an attempt

BEFORE

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" **href**="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group #1
              </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                This is a simple accordion inner content...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

AFTER

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" **data-target**="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group #1
              </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                This is a simple accordion inner content...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And now while there is no more redirect, it doesn't expand the accordion.

I understand that there is an AngularJS Accordion I can use, but I have a UI developer that does not know AngularJS and will give us codes in the above format, therefore, I want to bridge that gap whereby he gives us a piece of HTML that doesn't work as expected.

I noted that one of the comment mentioned.

*The above solution (also exactly the same in Bootstrap documentation) only works when not using Angular, at least for certain versions. I am assuming this is why the Angular folks created this library Angular UI Bootstrap as a workaround to these sorts of conflicts. Haven't investigated it fully to understand exactly the conflict, but this article sheds some light on possibly related conflicts due to jQuery. – michaelok Jan 8 '16 at 17:28*

What does *when not using Angular* means exactly in this case?

Comment: I think it means "when not using Angular" inside your application.

Comment: I'm confused... But the question posted by the others talks about AngularJS and we are facing the same problem.

Comment: Don't you use AngularJS inside your application?

Comment: Yes I do, but wouldn't it be the same for both the topics that faced the same issue?

Comment: Yes, both links you added to your question uses AngularJS. It's hard to develop an AngularJS app without having developers who knows how to deal with AngularJS.

Comment: So let's say I have 2 sets of developer. A User Interface developer and an AngularJS developer that handles the backend portion.

The idea was to have the UI Developer give us the User Interface, and we plug the necessary Angular stuffs into it. But it seems that if I use the common Bootstrap components, it doesn't work properly on an Angular project. 

Must my UI Developer really need to know Angular stuffs? All the NG components?

Comment: AngularJS is not a backend application, so why is your AngularJS developer handling your backend? Your UI developer should be aware about AngularJS and the requirments and limitations for creating an AngularJS frontend.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant was of the UI developer giving us a static HTML design and for us to replace the static text with the different logic handled by the Javascript.

The problem we are facing is that we are able to code the logic for the data to be displayed (parsing xml data and converting it to string format) but the UI design and CSS design are killing us as a UX team is in charge of coming up with the Wire-frame.

I went to bootsnipp.com and tried a few bootstrap components, but it failed to function as per expected. Thanks too for your quick responses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167083/discussion-between-alex-sim-and-lin).